# SSRS Matrix Last Column Item For Each Row

Tags: reporting-services

I need to find the last column item for each row in a matrix with multiple levels.

How could this be achieved?
If I use: =Last(Fields!XXX.Value) will get the last item for everything
If I use: =Last(Fields!XXX.Value, "Level1") will get the last item for Level1 only.

I need something like =Last(Fields!XXX.Value, "All Levels in Row")

Comment: On Which column you are using grouping ?

Comment: I will use grouping depending on the scope.